# Push Pop operations in Naviagtion view Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am trying to use a navigation view and execute the push and pop operations over it , But cant find where exactly i can define the object view , which would be used for view.push and view.pop.
cause i am getting this error that view isnt defined !
if trying to define Third_Navigate into a var view like

```
var view = Ext.define('MyFirstApp.view.Third_Naviagte', { .. });
```

then i am getting the error view.push isnt defined. Help.

```
Ext.define('MyFirstApp.view.Third_Naviagte', {
extend: 'Ext.navigation.View',
xtype: 'navigationview',
//itemId:'navView',
//we only give it one item by default, which will be the only item in the 'stack' when it loads
config:{
items: [
    {
        //items can have titles
        title: 'Navigation View',
        padding: 10,

        //inside this first item we are going to add a button
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Push another view!',
                handler: function() {
                   //when someone taps this button, it will push another view into stack
                    view.push({
                        //this one also has a title
                        title: 'Second View',
                        padding: 10,

                        //once again, this view has one button
                        items: [
                            {
                                xtype: 'button',
                                text: 'Pop this view!',
                                handler: function() {
                                    //and when you press this button, it will pop the current view (this) out of the stack
                                    view.pop();
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    });
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your example with `var view = Ext.define(...);` is not working is because **Ext.define** unlike **Ext.create** doesn't return an Object instance. It should be `var view = Ext.create(...);`.

Alternative way to do it would be using the [`up`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.2-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.Component-method-up) method used for selecting ancestors.

In your handler function use `this` to get the button instance and from there you can select the navigationview like so:

```
handler: function() {
    var view = this.up('navigationview');
    view.push({
        title: 'Second View',
        padding: 10,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Pop this view!',
                handler: function() {
                    view.pop();
                }
            }
        ]
    });
}
```